# How to add bootswatch theme or CDN to bootstrap-vue?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootswatch, bootstrap-vue

how do I use a theme from here:  https://bootswatch.com/

With bootstrap-vue from here: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs

In Nuxt.js:  https://nuxtjs.org/guide/modules#write-a-basic-module

I'm not an expert on any of these - what's the best way?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with a `nuxt.config.js` similar to this:

````
``` javascript
module.exports = {
  head: {
    link: [
      /* Option 1: Load from CDN */
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/4.1.2/pulse/bootstrap.min.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' },
    ],
  },
  css: [
    /* Option 2: Use from npm package here for custom CSS */
    'assets/main.scss'
  ],
  modules: [
    /* To use the above, turn off CSS from the package. */
    ['bootstrap-vue/nuxt', { css: false }],
  ],
}
```
````